# Line break when page is vertically full

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a page with a lot of Bootstrap 4 cards in a line.

I want to insert a line break when the vertical scroll bar would appear. How can I do that?

Code:

```
<?php
//THIS FILE IS A PART OF CROPSATH, LICENSED UNDER GPLv3.
//MADE BY MORICZGERGO A.K.A. SKIILAA
//CREATED: 2017.01.22.
//LAST MODIFIED: 2017.01.22.

include_once "include.php";

$conn = new mysqli($config->sqlServ, $config->sqlUser, $config->sqlPass, $config->dbName);

if ($conn->connect_error){
  echo "<center><h1>Failed to connect to database.</h1></center>";
  echo $conn->connect_error;
  die();
}

$sql = "SELECT questionName FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  echo "<div class=\"responsive-thingy\">";
  //output data of each row in bootstrap cards
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 20rem; display: table-cell;\"><div class=\"card-block\"><h4 class=\"card-text\">" . $row["questionName"] . "</h4></div></div>";
  }
  echo "</div>";
} else {
  echo "<center><h1>No questions found.</h1></center>";
}
?>
```

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Trofix/cropsath)

Comment: share some code please

Comment: @Anonymous I can't. It's just a lot of Bootstrap 4 cards in a row without line breaks.

Comment: @skiilaa  4 cards meaning what exactly?

Comment: @star bootstrap 4 card elements

Comment: Well, it is difficult to provide a solution without understanding your need :) A simple jsfiddle will go a long way !! note :http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @luciferous added code

Answer (score 0):

If it is text you are talking about you can use the '[hyphens](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/)' in css

Comment: No. I'm talking about the cards. I do not have line breaks after the cards.